# Colour the padding of a View

Tags: java, android, view, colors, padding

Say i have View A, which covers the whole screen

I then do

```
a.setPadding(90, 0, 90, 0)
```

So its now 90px down and 90 left

How can i colour these 90 pixels, say, red?

If i use .setBackgroundColour(int colour) it will, obviously, colour the whole View

So what should i do?

If this isn't possible, is it possible to have a View which is just red, 90 pixels wide, and covers that padded area? But still allows touch events to go through to the padded area

I need to do all this programatically

Comment: You could set a background color for a parent view.

Comment: use setBackgroundDrawable with a custom.    Drawable drawing the paddings in different color

Comment: @indivisible it is the parent

Comment: @pskink i need to use colour. Because the margins change

Comment: @HamzahMalik, but does it have to be? What's the issue with a View inside a View? Alternatively, If you are happy with a completely square border then you could use a Relative layout to put Views (of width/height matching your desired padding) touching the top, right, bottom and top edges and your desired view inside. Set the Views to have the same OnClickListener as your target View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom View that draws the color in the padding area. Here I am extending View, but you can extend something else if you desire.

```
package sample.package.name;

public class ColoredPaddingView extends View {
    Rect rect = new Rect();

    // Constructors omitted. Override them all and call the super constructor

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int l = getPaddingLeft();
        int t = getPaddingTop();
        int r = getWidth() - getPaddingRight();
        int b = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();
        rect.set(l, t, r, b);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(rect, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED); // or some other color
        canvas.restore;

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

In your layout XML, you would use the fully qualified class name of the view (including the package) like so:

```
<sample.package.name.ColoredPaddingView
     android:layout_width="..."
     android:layout_height="..."
     ... />
```

Comment: this colours the content, i wanted to colour the actual padding. To create a coloured frame of sorts. EDIT: it doesnt matter, i can set the content to white, and set the parent background, thanks!

Comment: The `canvas.clipRect` should omit the clipped area. It's possible I'm using the wrong Region.Op, but the goal was to only draw the non-content areas. Play around with it a bit and see if you can get it to do the right thing.